# Does CSL contain an empty string or not? Is empty string accepted by LBA or not?

Tags: turing-machines, automata, linear-bounded-automata

I am confused and got contradictory statements from various sources. It is mentioned in Page no 292, Chapter 11 A Hierarchy of Formal Languages & LBA, Peter Linz -An Introduction To Finite Automata, 5th Edition that "A language L is said to be CSL if there exists context-sensitive grammar G such that $L = L(G)$ or $L = L(G) \cup \{\varepsilon\}$." So the Language contains empty string & grammar as per Peter Linz.

In another version, I found that the production $S\to\varepsilon$ is also allowed in CSL, provided that 'S' does not appear on the right-hand side of any productions. However, several other sources like this youtube lecture (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3c_2c2KFpY) explain that CSL does not contain a null string. Here in this given link (https://gyires.inf.unideb.hu/GyBITT/14/ch06s04.html)  it is written that LBA accepts null string generated from a CSL.

In the book, "Theory of Computer Science: Automata, Languages and Computation" by Mishra K.L.P , third edition, Publisher-PhI, on page 299, subsection 9.8.1 that "The set of strings accepted by nondeterministic LBA is the set of strings generated by CSG, excluding null strings".

This is too much for making a complete confusion.
Example:

L=$\{a^nb^nc^n| n\geq 0 \}$, whether this is CSL or Not? This language contains empty string too!

Please help me to get the right knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to CS.SE!
I only know of the latter definition, i.e. the one allowing $S \to \varepsilon$ but disallowing $S$ in the right sides of productions.
Ultimately this is done to have a *nice* definition in the sense that the class of context-sensitive languages forms a proper superset of the class of context-free languages.
Definitions excluding the empty string to be in context-sensitive languages are a little bit less nice, in that sense.

As you found out, definitions may vary between sources and are often chosen in order to state some property or result in a particularly nice manner.
This is common in mathematics and another example would be the question of including 0 in the natural numbers $\mathbb N$ or not.
The thing is that usually these little changes do not really matter in the end; they do not fundamentally change the mathematical nature of the thing defined, and this is also the case with the small differences between the definitions for context-sensitive languages you encountered.